# Swift didReceiveRemoteNotification not called

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I have an app with oneSignal as push provider. I can receive push notifications, that work good. But if I try to access push payload I get nothing as `didReceiveRemoteNotification` not called.

I have following code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }

    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types : UIRemoteNotificationType =  [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if userInfo["d"] as! String == "t"  {

        print("key was received")

    }
    print(userInfo)
    print("PREVED")

}
```

Problem is that nothing prints out when I receive push. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the delegate method  is called or not'

Comment: the delegate method is not called

Comment: `registerUserNotificationSettings` is already deprecated from 10.0+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try once  your delegete method in this place

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
```

call this one

```
 func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Recived: \(userInfo)")

    completionHandler(.NewData)

}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2** - call this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    debugPrint("Received: \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

Comment: thanks, using this solved the problem for me, i was using a similar obsolete one...

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for Swift 3.0

```
//MARK: Push notification receive delegates

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                              didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                              fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {

        print("Recived: \(userInfo)")

        completionHandler(.newData)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Alexey make sure your **app provisioning file has enabled for Push Notification Service**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old post but solutions can be found here in my post [Push Notifications are delivered but didReceiveRemoteNotification is never called Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376255/push-notifications-are-delivered-but-didreceiveremotenotification-is-never-calle/56382289#56382289) or here [didReceiveRemoteNotification function doesn't called with FCM notification server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801107/didreceiveremotenotification-function-doesnt-called-with-fcm-notification-serve/56381878#56381878). 
Check for this parameter: `"content_available": true`in your notification definition or push notification service. With underscore is how it should be set.