# didReceiveRemoteNotification function doesn't called with FCM notification server

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, remote-notifications

I'm using FCM server for remote notifications, it worked perfectly with sending and receiving notifications.

My problem is when the device is in the background, this function `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` doesn't called.

Solutions that I've tried:

- This function:

  ```
  userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
  ```

is called when user tapped on the notification. Otherwise, it's not triggered.

- Adding `"content-available": true, "priority": "high"` to the payload. Also, I tried this value `"content-available": 1`.
- This is my function code:

```html
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        print("userInfo: \(userInfo)")
      completionHandler(.newData);
  
    }
```

Comment: If you are testing with **Postman** then try changing `"content-available": true` to `"content_available" : true`. **content-available** will send notification but it doesn't call `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Comment: Yes!! it solved with this solution! Thank you, you really helped me!

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you mind accepting it as an answer so it can help someone else too.

Comment: Sure! you deserve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing with **Postman** then try changing `"content-available": true` to `"content_available" : true`. **content-available** will send notification but it doesn't call `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding on accepted answer: in my case the problem was the same, but as I'm sending the Notification through an `http "POST" NSMUtableRequest` the way to apply the accepted answer was to actually add it in the notification parameters together with sound, badge, tiles etc etc..

```
let postParams: [String : Any] = [
                "to": receiverToken,
                "notification": [
                    "badge" : 1,
                    "body": body,
                    "title": title,
                    "subtitle": subtitle,
                    "sound" : true, // or specify audio name to play
                    "content_available": true, // this will call didReceiveRemoteNotification in receiving app, else won't work
                    "priority": "high"
                ],
                "data" : [
                    "data": "ciao",
            ]
                ]
```

Hope this will also help others, as I spent a long time trying to figure out how to apply this solution.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to see remote notification in background and foreground and show as alert when app run are this appDelegate.swift that i used in my code:

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate  {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm_message_id"
    var deviceID : String!


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {



        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
        return true

    }

    func showNotificationAlert(Title : String , Message : String, ButtonTitle : String ,window : UIWindow){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: Title, message: Message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ButtonTitle, style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // [START receive_message] remote notification
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.

        print(userInfo)

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)



        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }


        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let title = alert["title"] as? NSString {
                    let body = alert["body"] as? NSString
                    showNotificationAlert(Title: title as String, Message: body! as String, ButtonTitle: "Ok", window: window!)
                }
            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                print("mohsen 6 =\(alert)")
            }
        }
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)


        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        deviceID = fcmToken

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to check is the `Background Mode > Remote Notification` is on. If not, it will not be invoked in the background mode.

Comment: Yes it's checked in the project capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** – Add framework

```
import UserNotifications
```

**Step 2** – Inherit `AppDelegate` with `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

```
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {}
```

**Step 3** – Make appropriate changes for `registerPushNotifications` and call it `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
private func registerPushNotifications() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: { granted, error in

            if granted {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
            } else {
                    // Unsuccessful...
            }
          })
    } else {
        let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
   }
}
```

**Step 4** – Implement new handlers

```
    // leave this for older versions 
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
}

// For iOS10 use these methods and  pay attention how we can get userInfo
// Foreground push notifications handler
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    if let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
        // Getting user info
    }
    completionHandler(.Badge)
 }

// Background and closed  push notifications handler
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void)  {
    if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
        // Getting user info
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, I don’t want you to lose hope, Firebase has loads of problems in v5, this is, and was my method in Firebase 3 , when they messed it up; I had to switch to OneSignal. They also support CURL.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Because I have other problems that because of Firebase versions.

Comment: If you ever changed your mind, it’s not much of a choice; I’ll be here for any issues with OneSignal.

Answer (score 0):

As you tried i believe every thing , background permission is enable , content-available is the part of payload, you are also receiving notification in active state, last thing will be `Power save mode`,  you need to check is power saving is off; as if you Phone is in power saving mode, then background refresh and other process is gone in limited state, so app will not call `didReceivedNotifcation` in background.

Comment: I just tried your solution but unfortunately it doesn't called in the background.

Comment: `"content-available": 1`  should be the part of aps in payload ; Please check  apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1 ).